# How to know if due time is set

Tags: google-classroom

It seems google classroom API always returns a dueTime value - and if no time is selected when entering an assignment in classroom, 8:59 is used by default. How do I know if there was no time entered at all, or if 8:59 was really used?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://apiharmony-open.mybluemix.net/public/apis/google_classroom#post_v1_courses__courseId__courseWork):

***dueTime***

> description- Represents a time of day. The date and time zone are
>   either not significant or are specified elsewhere. An API may chose to
>   allow leap seconds. Related types are google.type.Date and
>   `google.protobuf.Timestamp`.,

**Note**: **Optional time of day**, in UTC, that submissions for this course work are due.
 **This must be specified if `due_date` is specified**.